# Send FCM data message using Firebase Console

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console, react-native-fcm, rich-notifications

Firebase cloud messaging service working very well compare to other push notification services and also very useful dashboard to see all the collection of details.

My requirement need to send image using Firebase Console (**data payload**/ **rich notification**) but it's not settled well.

I can able to send the text notification (**notification payload**) in firebase console and also it's working properly.

I can able to send the data payload message from **Post man** like below and its working properly.

[image: Postman Console]

[image: Notification with image in tray]

[image: Notification with image in content]

But Whenever I was trying to send image **key/value** pair in Additional options using **Firebase console** like below its not working. Please suggest.

[image: Firebase Console]

Comment: is there any update for this question????

Answer (score 0):

This is my own way, hope this will help you

[image]

[image]